# Capistrano+ssh+git: 'cap shell' 'git remote-ls' is OK, but 'cap deploy' falls on "Permission denied (public key)"

Tags: git, ssh, capistrano

I want to run `cap deploy` on my local machine (LOCAL_MACHINE), to do deployment on virtual machine (vagrant) (DEPLOY_SERVER). Sources are at git repository on third, remote, machine (GIT_SERVER).

When I run `cap staging deploy:update` on LOCAL_MACHINE, it connects to DEPLOY_SERVER, do some stuff and try to execute command

```
git ls-remote ssh://git@GIT_SERVER:7999/path/to/repo.git
```

And It ends with:

```
executing locally: " git ls-remote ssh://git@GIT_SERVER:7999/path/to/repo.git staging"
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
* executing "rm -rf /var/www/sites/my_site_staging/releases/20140117154348; true"
   servers: ["localhost"]
   [localhost:2222] executing command
  command finished in 71ms
Command  git ls-remote ssh://git@GIT_SERVER:7999/path/to/repo.git staging returned status code pid 4956 exit 128
```

BUT when I  run capistrano shell `cap shell` on my LOCAL_MACHINE, it connect to DEPLOYMENT_SERVER successfully.
Then I run (in the cap-shell) command

```
 git ls-remote ssh://git@GIT_SERVER:7999/path/to/repo.git staging
```

I get correct response:

```
 ** [out :: localhost:2222] adec1c91e5486a946be30845878cdd5b8420dcfe    refs/heads/staging
```

I do not want to use keys on my LOCAL_MACHINE (`ssh_options[:forward_agent] = false`), I have prepared deployer user on DEPLOYMENT_SERVER and it/he have (after log in) access to GIT_SERVER just using the keys on DEPLOYMENT_SERVER.

I am very confused that `cap shell command` works but `cap deploy` do not.

BTW: I am trying to test staging deploy on Vagrant Virtual machine (DEPLOYMENT_SERVER ssh: localhost:2222 ). But the same problem occurs on real staging server.

### EDITED:

I found that Capistrano 2.15.4 on `deploy:update_code`  is doing  `git ls-remote __repo_url__` from LOCAL_MACHINE, not from DEPLOY_SERVER.

It can be overwritten.

Original:

```
_cset(:real_revision) { source.local.query_revision(revision) { |cmd| with_env("LC_ALL", "C") { run_locally(cmd) } } }
```

overwritten in deploy.rb as:

```
set(:real_revision) { source.query_revision(revision) { |cmd| with_env("LC_ALL", "C") { run(cmd) } } }
```

which will run succesfully command on DEPLOY_SERVER, but somehow do not get the results trought. Instead:

```
 "7a8164e340e724b1c96c28ed925f6e41194daed7\trefs/heads/master\n004d1efd07b432cab6d7924df1ef7c3cd0c8bedb\trefs/remotes/origin/master\n"
```

you got

```
 nil
```

Comment: hi, I would love to know how you got around this. I'm having a hard time figuring it out as well.